# Is Oracle DB licensing needed for a test environment?

Tags: oracle, license, oracle-se

I'm planning to setup an Oracle Standard Edition instance on a server in our test environment.

Do I need to purchase a license for this?

Answer (score 13):

In general, yes.  Once you have an application in production, every environment (dev, test, staging, production, etc.) needed to support that application needs to be licensed.  As with all licensing advice, however, you need to get it in writing from Oracle Sales.  Advice from some guy on the internet holds up about as well as you might expect if there is ever a question about whether you're properly licensed and/or if you're overpaying for licenses.  And remember that agreements your company has with Oracle, laws in your country, etc. can change this general statement.

If you are a reasonably large customer or if you have some other leverage in the negotiation process, however, you can generally get the licenses for the test and development environments at a good discount from Oracle Sales.

Comment: With the phrase "Once you have an application in production" you seem to be indicating that if the application has never been in production, or there is no application and the system is just being setup, that no license is necessary.  Is this what you meant.

Comment: If it is a brand new application in the development/ prototyping phase, the OTN license would generally let you use the Oracle software free of charge.  There is a clear bright line when the application goes to production that all your environments need to be licensed.  Realistically, that leaves some grey area (i.e. a database on a developer's laptop that isn't officially part of the build environment and is sometimes used to prototype new apps but is sometimes used in support of a production application) but those grey areas generally aren't what get people into trouble.

Comment: Good followup.  +1.

Comment: I was always confused by this "for testing and development" part of the OTN license. What if I develop an application that never goes into production in _my_ environment, because I deliver the binaries to a customer who then puts it into production (and _does_ have an Oracle license)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Then you are clearly using it for testing purposes only, while your customer uses it for production purposes.

Answer (score 8):

The [Oracle Software Investment Guide](http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/pricing/sig-070616.pdf) says the following:

> *Test/Staging* - Test/staging
>   environments are used to verify that
>   new or customized code runs properly.
>   This can be staged on separate servers
>   or on the same servers used to run a
>   development or production environment.
>   Any Oracle software used in
>   test/staging environment must be
>   properly licensed with a Full Use
>   license under an Oracle License and
>   Services Agreement (OLSA) or other
>   appropriate Oracle (or Oracle
>   authorized reseller) license
>   agreement. If a test/staging
>   environment is maintained on the same
>   server as a production or development
>   environment, and that server is fully
>   licensed for all relevant programs on
>   a per Processor metric, then no
>   additional licenses are required for
>   the test/staging environment.

If you have a fully licensed server with a virtualized database running on it, you might want to consider adding a second virtual machine to the same server to run your test system on.  It would save you from having to purchase an additional license if the resources can accommodate it.

Comment: But then the [OTN License](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/licenses/standard-license-152015.html) states you can install and use it as long as you don't put that system into production

Comment: A system that has no production piece is considered a prototype environment and would fall under the OTN License, but as soon as you need to do testing on an environment that is in production, that testing would not be prototyping and would therefore require a license as stated above - at least that is my understanding.